# Format array from sql query result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following query

```
$sql = "SELECT nomInteretUser from userInteret where idUser='$id_user' ";
$result = $conn->query(sprintf($sql));
```

I want to produce an array with following structure: `array ('User1','User2')`

I have tried this :

```
if ($result->num_rows != 0) {
    $rows=array(); 
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
        $rows[]=$r;
    } 
}
```

But it gives following result:

```
{
   array(1) {
       ["nomInteretUser"]=> "foot"
   }
   array(1) {
       ["nomInteretUser"]=> "cyclisme"
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `$rows[]=$r["nomInteretUser"]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$rows[]=$r['nomInteretUser'];` in your code than you get the right result. :)

```
if ($result->num_rows != 0) {
    $rows=array(); 
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 
        $rows[]=$r['nomInteretUser'];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply update your code to :

```
if($result)
{           
   if ($result->num_rows != 0) {

      $rows=array(); 

      while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      { 
         $rows[]=$r["nomInteretUser"];
      } 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this 2 ways:

1. Please update your current code like this

   ```
   while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   { 
       $rows[]=$r['nomInteretUser'];  //Update here
   }
   ```
2. If you don't want to update your current code then modify code, then use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (`>= PHP 5.5` Required)

   `$rows = array_column($rows, 'nomInteretUser');`

Hope it helps!